# Java: JavaMail, POP3 and few problems

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, pop3

I'd like to ask few questions about handling POP3 protocol with JavaMail (I'm building small web mail client):

1. How do I know which mail is new? Mail server doesn't provide this info explicitely. I have to iterate thru all mails and check with my database, which are new
2. What if someone sends a really big attachment? Is there way how not to download it and limit it to certain size? Like with MimePart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. POP offers only two reliable ways to keep track of which messages you've already downloaded.  First is to delete them after downloading, which you evidently don't want to do.  And second is to track UIDLs in your local database.
2. There is no way to download a subset of message parts via POP, as POP doesn't include a message structure model.  You can fetch the first N lines from a message if the POP server supports [the `TOP` command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1939#page-11), but that probably isn't what you want.

It sounds like you want IMAP, not POP.

Comment: I need both IMAP and POP, but POP simply troubles me :(

Comment: POP was made for a purpose.  For taking mail off a server and onto local disk, it does an OK job.  Unfortunately, that's not what you're doing...

Comment: Exactly.  That's what POP does: fetches entire messages verbatim and lets you remove them from the server.  You want something that's state- and structure-aware, that's IMAP.